# Sqlite каскадное удаление данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте.Необходимо при удалении данных из таблицы test что бы удалялись данные и из таблиц test2 и test3.Например при удалении записей из таблицы test1 с _id=1, что бы и из таблиц test2 и test3 удалялись данные с baseid=1.Создаю таблицы с внешними ключами

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,baseid INTEGER);
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,baseid INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY (baseid) REFERENCES test(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test3 (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,baseid INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY (baseid) REFERENCES test(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Удаляю все данные из таблицы test данные также удаляются и из test2,но из test3 нет.Причем так происходит в андроид,а на компе sqlite3 удаляет все как надо.Подскажите как это решить.

Answer (score 1):

Может это поможет

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

Foreign key не поддерживается по умолчанию в SQLite.

Comment: установил я это дело.Удаляет да только из 2 таблиц из 3 нет.Вроде так и нельзя.